# Version control for non-hierarchical file system

Tags: version-control, hierarchical

Version control systems that I am aware of (SVN, git, Mercurial, fossil, ...) assume a hierarchical organization of files in directories.

Are there systems which work, say, for database file systems? Ideally I would like my files to be organized similar like the songs are in iTunes.